# Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1 - But the query works in Navicat

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to get the parameters from a table and insert them into a different table but I always get this error: Error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

The funny part is that it does insert a few rows and for some I get the error. I have checked the number of columns to match with the number of values and everything seems right. And whenever I debug the code and select the content of my Insert command and execute it into Navicat it works.

Does anyone has any ideas why I'm getting this error?

This is my code:

```
private void CopylmtValues()
{
        if (ObjSqlAccess.Connected)
        {

            DtSqlSettings.Clear();

            string InsertLmtPara = "";
            int rows2 = 0;

            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
            progressBar1.Minimum = rows2;
            progressBar1.Maximum = DtSqlSettings.Rows.Count;


            string GetlimitsVls = "Select * from `" + comboBox1.Text + "`.`limitvalues` where LimitID = (Select LimitID from `"+ comboBox1.Text +"`.`limits` where LimitChecksum = '" + comboBox8.Text + "')";                                    
            DtSqlSettings = ObjSqlAccess.GetDataTableFromTable(GetlimitsVls);

            label8.ResetText();
            label8.Text = "" + DtSqlSettings.Rows.Count + " rows has been found!";

            string lmtval = "";
            string lmt1 = "";
            string lmt2 = "";
            string lmt3 = "";
            string lmt4 = "";
            string lmt5 = "";
            string lmt6 = "";
            string lmt7 = "";
            string lmt8 = "";
            string lmt9 = "";
            string lmt10 = "";
            string lmt11 = "";
            string lmt12 = "";

            bool Getrows2 = false;
            //bool CheckDuplication = false;

            if (DtSqlSettings != null)
            {
                 while(rows2 != DtSqlSettings.Rows.Count)
                {
                    string getlmtID = "Select distinct LimitID from `" + comboBox1.Text + "`.limits where LimitChecksum = '" + comboBox8.Text + "'";
                    limitID = ObjSqlAccess.GetDataTableFromTable(getlmtID);


                        lmtval = limitID.Rows[0][0].ToString();
                        lmt1 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][2].ToString();
                        lmt2 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][3].ToString();
                        lmt3 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][4].ToString();
                        lmt4 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][5].ToString();
                        lmt5 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][6].ToString();
                        lmt6 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][7].ToString();
                        lmt7 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][8].ToString();
                        lmt8 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][9].ToString();
                        lmt9 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][10].ToString();
                        lmt10 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][11].ToString();
                        lmt11 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][12].ToString();
                        lmt12 = DtSqlSettings.Rows[rows2][13].ToString();

                        if(!Getrows2)
                        {

                             InsertLmtPara = "INSERT INTO `" + comboBox2.Text + "`.limitvalues " +
                                            "(`LimitID`,`Location`,`TestID`,`Description`,`LimitType`,`UnitType`,`LowLimit`,`HighLimit`,`NominalValue`,`StringLimit`,`TestFunction`,`ID`,`SubID`)" +
                                            " VALUES ('"+ lmtval +"','" + lmt1 + "','" + lmt2 + "','" + lmt3 + "','" + lmt4 + "','" + lmt5 + "'," + lmt6 + "," + lmt7 + ",'" + lmt8 + "','" + lmt9 + "','" + lmt10 + "','" + lmt11 + "','" + lmt12 + "')";
                            int InsertPARA = ObjSqlAccess.ExecuteNoneQuery(InsertLmtPara);

                            progressBar1.PerformStep();

                            if(rows2 == DtSqlSettings.Rows.Count)
                            {
                                Getrows2 = true;

                            }

                            rows2++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: isnt your query open to sql injection like this? correct me if am wrong...

Comment: probably yes! I also tried to use escape correctors , maybe it could've been from one of the quotes but it still didn't worked.

Comment: Adding parameters will be safer

Comment: Put a breakpoint at line **int InsertPara = Obj..** And hover mouse Over InsertLmtPara, right click, copy value, apply in on ssms and check

Comment: when you say ssms what are you referring to?

Comment: This is my result:                                                                                       INSERT INTO `localHost`.limits(`LimitID`,`Location`,`tID`,`Description`,`LimitType`,`UnitType`,`LowLimit`,`HighLimit`,`NominalValue`,`StringLimit`,`TestFunction`,`ID`,`SubID`) VALUES ('23','KD-sdsSS','1','Log - Time - System Idle','0','ms','0','1E+08','0','','\Generic\Late\Time_to_Log\Time to Log, Simple V.1.22.G.va','0','1')

Comment: ssms is Sql Server Management Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be happening cauz of a kind of injection. Adding parameters is a better way. I'll show you an example of the cause

I have a table with cols : **Name, Age, Address**

If i try to insert some value like

'Salim', 28, 'St.Anthony's Colony, Chennai's 27th AVN'

.

The supplied values here will be :

'Salim',

28,

'St.Anthony's Colony,

Chennai's 27th AVN'

.

The sql engine first looks for the supplied values count and return this kind of error.

.

**You can use Parameters like this**

```
    string name = "Salim";
    string addr = "St.Anthony's Colony, Chennai's 27th AVN";
    int age = 28;

    string query = "Insert Into StaffDetails ([Name], [Age], [Address]) Values (@name, @age, @address)";

    IDbCommand comm = new IDbCommand (query, connection);

    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@age", age);
    comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", addr);

    comm.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Comment: I will try figure it out hot to add parameters instead and comeback with an answer. I still find it strange because it is not the first time when I am using this query with this form and never experienced this error!

Comment: Within the above sample i 've shown you can see that, it happens only in some cases when people supply address having quotes inside

Comment: Ok, I just figured it out what you mean by that. Because of that coma  it will not reconize it as one word and it will split it, right?

Comment: Yes. I will show you how to use parameters if you are using System.Data.Sql

Comment: Yes, that would be great!

Comment: Yes! I will try it tomorrow and if I get to any results I will definitely vote!

Comment: Is there maybe another way to confront with this issues besides the parameters solutions? I have to re-write all my connection settings in order to implement your example and I don't really want to do that because the rest of my programme is built on those settings!

Comment: By adding parameters, you're just changing the Sqlcommand, how come that change your connection settings?

Comment: I am not using SQLcommand in my settings....only IDbCommand and IDb Connection and it is not set up like you see on any examples as: SqlConnection blabla = new SqlConnection("my connection settings")

Comment: IDbCommand also has got parameters property in it. And you dont have to do the whole testing. If you want to check a specific one, Add a new form do a testing by a simple insert query in the Form's constructor method, set that form as the statup form temporarily and check.

Comment: And if it works, you can apply everywhere by simply adding an IDbParameterCollection in your ObjSqlAccess Class, assign parameters to it and execute **or** overload your ObjSqlAccessClass.ExecuteNonQuery with additional parameter of IDbParameter Collection.

Comment: I will give it a try and comeback with a comment! Thanks!

Comment: I have used escape correctors and it worked! Thank you for your time! I have no doubt that your solution works but wanted to keep the same style.